# GORM failed when changing to using pgx: migrator.go:206:65: undefined: gorm.ColumnType

Tags: database, postgresql, go, go-gorm

I had this on my go project using GORM:

```
import (
    (...)
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
)

func main() {
    (...)
    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
}
```

I was able to open the connection to the DB and do all my transactions. If I change to:

```
import (
    (...)
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
)

func main(){
    (...)
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
}
```

it will give me an error on **go build**:

```
# gorm.io/driver/postgres
$GOPATH\pkg\mod\gorm.io\driver\postgres@v1.0.5\migrator.go:206:65: undefined: gorm.ColumnType
$GOPATH\pkg\mod\gorm.io\driver\postgres@v1.0.5\migrator.go:207:23: undefined: gorm.ColumnType
```

I got this from the official page:
https://gorm.io/docs/connecting_to_the_database.html

Answer (score 1):

I changed to using the same library... my bad.
Instead of

```
   "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
```

use this:

```
    "gorm.io/gorm"
```

along the same driver
So now it looks like this:

```
import (
    (...)
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
)

func main(){
    (...)
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to upgrade to a newer version of gorm.
I got this error when using `v1.20.4`.
`gorm.io/gorm v1.20.7` works for me